# How can I make an entire folder and its descendants available to UIMA (Ruta, Uimafit) as resources?

Tags: java, classpath, uima, ruta

I have used the `WORDLIST` functionality to great effect with the default `UIMA Ruta` project. However, the `Ruta` project structure is not appropriate for use with a production web app, for instance.

Is there a way to make entire folders or the classpath in general to `UIMA` when using it from Java?

For clarity and simplicity, what I think I would like to do is to keep all my `UIMA` stuff under a single root folder. I was thinking `src/main/ruta` even though technically there would be non-source files there. Then, the structure under `src/main/ruta` could mirror the kind of structure you get when you create the default `UIMA Ruta` project.

The only issue with that is that the default structure put things in different folder by type but also respects folders when it comes to namespacing the scripts. So below are two different ways I might do it - the first being the way it is out of the box and the second being the way it would be in what I would describe as the most natural way to do it...

```
src/
 main/
  java/
  resource/ <--- maybe I should put it in here instead
  ruta/
   descriptor/
    BasicEngine.xml
    BasicTypeSystem.xml
    com/
     tacos/
      FubuEngine.xml
      FubuTypeSystem.xml
   resource/
    com/
     tacos/
      FubuWordList1.txt
      FubuWordList2.txt
      FubuWordList1.twl
      FubuWordList2.twl
      FubuWordLists.mtwl 
   script/
     com/
      tacos/
       Fubu.ruta
```

Comment: You included the android-resources tag; does this mean that your program is meant to run on Android? Android and Java are not the same...

Comment: Whoops; I meant to use `embedded-resources` but I ended up pressing the wrong thing; I just got rid of it because it wouldn't have been incredibly helpful anyway

Comment: Sorry, I did not yet understood the problem completely. Why does it not work with a production web app? Is it a problem with absolute paths? ... and which ones are the source folders in your example? Most important: Is there a specific exception?

Comment: Well I didn't try it because it's not that it wouldn't work so much as it wouldn't *work*, as in that folder structure is a bit much for committing to a web app in which currently the only folder is src

Comment: Ah ok. I personally prefer to work with the classpath instead of the *Paths configuration parameters. I put the scripts (and their packages) in the source folder src/main/ruta and the wordlists (and theirs folder structure) in src/main/resources. I do not use a separate descriptor folder. The descriptors are generated by the ruta-maven-plugin, which creates a source folder in target. Then, all stuff in the classpath (target/classes) and is packaged in the jar in order to be used/included, e.g., in a webapp.

Comment: Sweet - thanks for the help too. I was looking for both honestly because yes everyone likes the classpath by default to just work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set `resourcePaths`? In java, the parameter name is `RutaEngine.PARAM_RESOURCE_PATHS`. See [this documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.basic).

Comment: That works, and no I did not ... but I have a related question(s): 1) isn't this specifiable from the engine description xml file? 2) wouldn't it be better to keep it there if it doesn change 3) how can I make the UIMA ruta project respect my paths?

Comment: 1) yes, it can be specified in the xml 2) yes 3) you mean the Ruta workbench?

Comment: yes - and that brings me to the next question, which is... what would be the right XML file to which to add this reference (it generates a bunch that seem to be very purpose-specific). Should I use `BasicEngine` One thing that I think would ease people into Ruta is to have a project configured as a maven project with the Ruta project so that both are available (workbench for testing, maven for execution and deployment), referencing the same files, with no duplicates and no namespace issues... maybe if I ifgure it all out I'll make one

Comment: There are a few exemplary projects that combine maven with ruta, e.g., 'example-projects/ruta-maven-example', some intergation tests in 'ruta-maven-plugin/src/it' or here [date-example.zip](http://people.apache.org/~pkluegl/examples/)

Comment: The IDE should work with maven projects if the ruta-maven-plugin is correctly configured (buildpath settings). However, there are some bugs in ruta-2.3.1 concerning this which are already fixed in the current trunk and will be part of the next release.